# Are there arbitrarily large data structures in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I need a data structure like Sequence that can be longer than maxBound::Int, but I can't find *any* data structures which allow this. Is there a library for very large containers? Is Haskell simply unable to handle these, despite have "infinite" types?

Comment: A `Sequence` itself is arbitrary large, for indexing however, it uses by default an `Int`. A list is also arbitrary large, one can index this with `genericIndex` for example: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex

Comment: In fact a lot of datastructures (like `[a]`, `Tree a`, etc. are arbitrary large).

Comment: `Sequence` internally stores its size as an `Int` so it is actually limited in size by the implementation, not only the interface.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia: ah ok. Did not know that, that's a bit sad :(.

Comment: Thank you, Willem. What I don't understand is the warning about undefined behavior beyond sizes of maxBound::Int. I want to index with Integers, and I want finite list-like structures with length > maxBound::Int. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? If you have more than `maxBound :: Int` elements (which are the size of a machine word) then you will start running into hardware limitations, 2^64 is astronomically large, and even if you somehow had the memory, you would run out of pointers before getting there.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, I'm writing a tool for mathematical logic, and I'd like to prove that, given enough memory, it has correct semantics. To have correct semantics, arbitrarily large terms need to be available (in principle). To achieve this, I need a potentially-large RoseTree where each node is a symbol in my language and each leaf is a non-negative Integer. The children of a node are its arguments, so this is basically an abstract syntax tree satisfying some constraints. If I can solve the special case of an unbounded Sequence-like structure, then I can get an unbounded RoseTree-like structure.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it is a bit sad, but using `Natural` for the size tracking would be quite a bit less efficient. Almost every internal node of each tree would be two words larger, and each of the many size computations involved in various operations would be quite a bit more expensive. Indexing, splitting, adjusting/updating, inserting, and deleting would be hit hardest, but almost every operation (I think basically all but non-indexed folds and traversals) would slow down substantially.

Comment: @MonadMania as Willem said, there's `[a]`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia: not only out of pointers, but also likely out of cpu cycles. Unless you simply store data, etc. if you do something interesting with data, it will usually require a multitude of cycles per data element.

Comment: There's the [`fingertree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree) package. You can use this with `Natural` measure to build unlimited-length finite sequences pretty easily.